# Can Ubuntu use a flash drive to increase performance like ReadyBoost?

Tags: flash, lubuntu, memory, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way that an external hard drive can be used to boost performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133879/is-there-any-way-that-an-external-hard-drive-can-be-used-to-boost-performance)

This might be a silly question but is there any way to use a flash drive to optimize the memory on lubuntu 12.04? Kinda like how you can in win7?

Comment: take a look over this discussion http://askubuntu.com/q/133879/35775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, No.  ReadyBoost is a disk cache component of Windows, works by using flash memory, a USB flash drive, as cache, **NOT** as swap.  Plus too much I/O operations in a flash drive can damage it in a long run.

Nowadays RAM is cheap, so you'd better off using RAM, since USB is slower than RAM.  Or you can use SSD.